# Synonym for 'arrive independently' at same solution

Tags: synonyms

In biology, [convergent evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_evolution) describes the process whereby different animals acquire similar traits in separate lineages.

Two people can arrive at the same solution to a problem, or invent something, without the influence of each other.

Is there a word (or phrase) that sums up the coincidence of 'arriving independently' at the same solution? A convergent solution? Synchronicity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of articles online that call it [*simultaneous invention*](http://www.kk.org/thetechnium/archives/2008/05/simultaneous_in.php) or [*simultaneous discovery*](http://www.newyorker.com/reporting/2008/05/12/080512fa_fact_gladwell#ixzz1gICdb3SJ):

> This phenomenon of simultaneous discovery—what science historians call
>   “multiples”—turns out to be extremely common.

Wikipedia calls it *[multiple discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_discovery)*:

> The concept of multiple discovery is the hypothesis that most
>   scientific discoveries and inventions are made independently and more
>   or less simultaneously by multiple scientists and inventors. The
>   concept of multiple discovery opposes a traditional view—the "heroic
>   theory" of invention and discovery.

Comment: One possible mechanism for this is called bunching phenomena. http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/busses-come-in-threes-why-do-proofs-come-in-twos/

Comment: That was perhaps for want of a better expression. I just cannot see how *simultaneous invention*, *simultaneous discovery* or *multiple discovery* can preclude the possible meaning of "**someone** inventing/ discovering several **things** at a time", rather than as intended.